# Require.js/Jquery Datable : undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, datatables

I am trying to load JQuery datatables with Require.js

This is my JS module where I would like to use datatables :

```
define([
  "jquery",
  "text!orders_list.tpl",
  "dataTables"
  ], function($, OrdersListTemplate, dataTables)
{
  console.log($);
  console.log($.fn.dataTable);
  ... more logic after
```

How I call my JS module in HTML :

```
require(['./js/config'], function (common) 
{
  require(
    [
      'js/modules/init',
      ...
      'js/modules/orders_list.js'
    ],
    function (init, ..., orders_list)
    {
      init.initialize();
      ...
      orders_list.initialize();
    });
});
```

How I have defined my config :

```
require.config({
  shim: {
    underscore: {
      exports: '_'
    },
    backbone: {
      deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
      exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    ...
  },
  paths: {
    jquery:           '../../shops_common/js/lib/jquery-1.9.1',
    backbone:         '../../shops_common/js/lib/backbone.min',
    underscore:       '../../shops_common/js/lib/underscore.min',
    dataTables:       'http://datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables'
  },
  waitSeconds: 300
});
```

But $.fn.dataTable is always undefined...
Any idea why?

Thanks.

Comment: Moreover, I tried with an other plugin (tablesorter) and it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after extensive research: Datatables is a named module you must use the name "datatables" in your require